# Что делать с Wi-Fi на ноутбуке?

Tags: wifi, сеть, железо, ноутбук

Здравствуйте.
Ноутбук (Lenovo G570, возраст - 3 года) в последнее время стал плохо работать с Wi-Fi сетью:

- медленная передача данных;
- не подключается к сети, но видит её    (уровень сигнала - 3/4);
- не видит ни одну сеть (но они там точно    есть).

Я думаю, что проблемы с Wi-Fi картой, хочу купить внешнюю - поможет ли это? Если да, то больше ничего не надо?

P. S. ОС - Linux Fedora 22 WORKSTATION, Microsoft Windows 7 "Starter" - работает одинаково плохо.
P. P. S. Wi-Fi соседа, но проблема точно не в нём.

Comment: Подтверждаю, Wi-Fi в ноутбуках обычно сменный, сам недавно заменил в своём (Acer Aspire 5750G, и ему больше трёх лет). В процессе, правда, пришлось прошить свежий BIOS, поскольку после установки начались феерические спецэффекты, спасло только это.

Comment: @D-side да, с биосом будут заморочки, если не угадать с моделью. лучше брать точно такую же карту, что стояла раньше.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Должно помочь. Использую [такую](http://www.tp-linkru.com/products/details/?model=tl-wn722n). Поведение хорошее как на linux так и на windows. С такой [антенной](http://radioaktiv.ru/publ/antenna/wifi/95-publ_24.html) вообще красота.

Comment: И потом таскать за ноутом направленную антенну :)

Comment: @Visman чего только не сделаешь ради интернета ;) двух сторонний скотч в помощь :)

Answer (score 2):

Wi-Fi модули в ноутбуках - это Mini PCI модули. Иногда в них же вшит и Bluetooth. Они сменные - достаточно разобрать ноут, выдернуть карточку из гнезда на материнке, воткнуть новую и переподключить антенны - два провода от карты, которые уходят в крышку ноутбука. Выглядит карта примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Производители ноутбуков прошивают в биос конкретные модели карт - они сертифицируют ноуты по FCC и прочим стандартам, в которых прописан уровень излучения.

Так что лучше искать точно такую, какая была установлена Lenovo. Для G570 это скорее всего Anatel Atheros AR5B95, 9.99$ на eBay - та, что на картинке выше. Но лучше заранее разобрать и проверить.